# (HTML/CSS) Linking from the same page to specific times of embedded youtube video

Tags: html, css, video, youtube, timestamp

I have an embedded youtube video, which starts at 0:00:00. It's followed by a paragraph with examples from the video, each with a timestamp. Is there a way to link these timestamps back to the video, so that clicking on each one would shift the starting point of the video to that particular point?

Thanks!

```
<div class="video">
  <iframe width="100%" height="360px"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7A6K2BeCMz0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>     
</div>
```

...

```
<p>I can warmly recommend watching the entire movie, but here’s a shortlist of the strongest moments: Sergey’s being flogged by Boris (41:25), the poisoning of Boris (44:53); Zinovij return and death (1:05:04); the scene with the shabby little man (1:11:06, and especially the orchestral interlude at 1:14:00); the song of the exiled to Siberia (1:22:49—“O, you, road ploughed by chains, / the road to Siberia, sown with bones, / this road has been watered with blood and sweat, / death groans arise from it…”); the purest, most lyrical moment of the opera—Katerina’s words to Sergey as they meet after a day’s march (1:29:12—“Seryozha, my dearest! At last! I’ve gone the whole day without seeing you, Seryozha! Even the pain in my legs has gone, and the tiredness, and the grief, now you are with me…”). And finally, her final monologue, terrible in its disconnectedness, after Sergey’s betrayal, as for the first time since the opera began she understands what she’d done, and we see the dark chasm yawning before her (1:38:10)</p>
```

Comment: Anyone?... any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YouTube iFrame API contains [the function](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls) `player.seekTo(seconds:Number, allowSeekAhead:Boolean):Void`. It requires implementing the iFrame using JavaScript however. You can find instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls).

Comment: Thanks very much. Will try that.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Link the timestamp to Youtube URL plus a start parameter (value is the seconds of starting point)

For you case, link 41:25 to https://www.youtube.com/embed/7A6K2BeCMz0?start=2485

Comment: Thanks – have just tried that, but it opens a new window with a player. What I'd need it to do is link to the video *which is already embedded earlier on the page* (first bit of code above), but shift its starting point to the new time-point.